# How can I retrieve a Point from SQL Server with C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-3.1

i'm using spacial data type on my sql server and I want to retrieve this data from my sql server to my Entity Class, it returns the error **".NET number values such as positive and negative infinity cannot be written as valid JSON."** when i try to Get the value from my db.

Coordinates is the value I want to return from my db. I'm using Geography data type from NetTopologySuite and i'm inserting a Point from my Entity Class.

[image]

The class code that i'm using:

```
public class Address : EntityBase<int>
{
    public Address () {}

    public Address(string district, string street, int number, string complement, string zipCode, 
    string cityDescription, string stateDescription, Point coordinates, int countryId, byte stateId, int cityId)
    {
        District = district;
        Street = street;
        Number = number;
        Complement = complement;
        ZipCode = zipCode;
        CityDescription = cityDescription;
        StateDescription = stateDescription;
        Coordinates = coordinates;
        CountryId = countryId;
        StateId = stateId;
        CityId = cityId;
    }

    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Complement { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string CityDescription { get; set; }
    public string StateDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual Point Coordinates { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public byte StateId { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int? StoreId { get; set; }
    public int? ProfessionalId { get; set; }
}
```

And the sql server code for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Address(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    District VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, -- Bairro
    Street VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, -- Rua
    --Description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Number INT,
    Complement VARCHAR(100),
    ZipCode VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CityDescription VARCHAR(100),
    StateDescription VARCHAR(100),
    Coordinates GEOGRAPHY,
    
    CountryId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Country(Id) NOT NULL,
    StateId TINYINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES State(Id),
    CityId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES City(Id),
    CustomerId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(Id),
    StoreId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Store(Id),
    ProfessionalId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Professional(Id),

    INDEX IndexAddressCountryId NONCLUSTERED (CountryId),
    INDEX IndexAddressStateId NONCLUSTERED (StateId),
    INDEX IndexAddressCityId NONCLUSTERED (CityId),
    INDEX IndexAddressCustomerId NONCLUSTERED (CustomerId),
    INDEX IndexAddressStoreId NONCLUSTERED (StoreId),
    INDEX IndexAddressProfessionalId NONCLUSTERED (ProfessionalId)
)
```

Is there any method to retrieve the Point value from this? Like a configuration on function **OnModelCreating** or something else? Can I only retrieve the longitude and latitude from it?

I'm new to Spacial Data so I don't know much about it. Thanks in advance for helping me :)

---

Edit 1:

Here's the exception error that i get:

[image]

EntityBase:

```
namespace CodenApp.Framework.Core.Entities
{
    public abstract class EntityBase<T>
    {
        public T Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the two functions that I use to handle Exceptions:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, ex.ToString());                
        await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
    }
}


protected override Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
{
    if(context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    if(exception == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(exception));

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    return context.Response.WriteAsync(ApiCatch.Log(exception).ToString());
}
```

The code that I used to convert to Point:

```
public static Point ConvertToGeometry(string coordinatesAux)
{
    if(coordinatesAux == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    NumberFormatInfo formatProvider = new NumberFormatInfo();
    formatProvider.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
            
    var currentLocation = new Point(new Coordinate(
                                        Convert.ToDouble(coordinatesAux.Substring(0, coordinatesAux.IndexOf(",")), formatProvider), 
                                        Convert.ToDouble(coordinatesAux.Substring(coordinatesAux.IndexOf(",") + 1), formatProvider))) { SRID = 4326 };
            
    return currentLocation;                                                            
}
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with EF Core or Spatial data. What is the *actual* exception text? You can get this easily with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` on the exception popup. The full text contains the stack trace that shows which chain of method calls led to that exception. Post the *actual* code that throws this exception

Comment: Spatial data has nothing to do with JSON. It was added to SQL Server in 2008, 8 years before JSON support was added. Whatever throws this exception, isn't related to Spatial Data. BTW what is `EntityBase`? Does it have any code that converts from/to JSON?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's why i'm asking, because I can easily post the value but when I try to retrieve it I got that error, so I don't know what is causing it. I'm using swagger to test my API

Comment: I only know that it throws the exception when it calls the getter from public virtual Point Coordinates.

Comment: Do you have code that was used to save coordinate?  The coordinate was converted to the string byte array and you need to use the library methods write string, but use reverse method to get the numeric values of the coordinate.

Comment: The stack trace shows this is thrown when converting the object to JSON, not when retrieving it. `System.Text.Json` knows nothing about geometries and will try to serialize all of the object's properties, the same as any other object. This includes properties which may contain default values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so... how can I do it? Create a custom function to convert the object to JSON?

Comment: You need to create a custom JsonConverter for this type and register it with ASP.NET Core. It's ASP.NET Core that calls System.Text.Json to convert the data to JSON. It's quite possible that NetTopologySuite or a related package already contains such a converter

Comment: [There's a NuGet for this](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/wiki/Using-NTS.IO.GeoJSON4STJ-with-ASP.NET-Core-MVC)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that worked for me, so I posted the solution, thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) said in the comments, to solve this situation I needed to add the NuGet package [NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ) and change the file Startup.cs to recieve the changes given by the package.

Changes in Startup.cs inside ConfigureServices function:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(Point))); 
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(Coordinate))); 
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(LineString))); 
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(MultiLineString))); 
});

services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    var geoJsonConverterFactory = new GeoJsonConverterFactory();
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(geoJsonConverterFactory);
});

services.AddSingleton(NtsGeometryServices.Instance);
```

And added the IOptions to my Controller:

```
private readonly IOptions<JsonOptions> _jsonOptions;
public StoreController(IAsyncRepository<Store, int> repository, StoreHandler handler, IOptions<JsonOptions> jsonOptions) : base(repository)
{
    _handler = handler;
    _orders = new Expression<Func<Store, object>>[] { x => x.Id };
    _jsonOptions = jsonOptions;
}
```

So taught in this [wiki](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/wiki/Using-NTS.IO.GeoJSON4STJ-with-ASP.NET-Core-MVC).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply JSON ignore the porperty causing issues and create properties that display values in an acceptable format.
Here is how I went about this:

```
public class LocationResult
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public GeoCoordinate geo { get; set; }
    public double latitude
    {
        get
        {
            return geo.Latitude;
        }
    }
    public double longitude
    {
        get
        {
            return geo.Longitude;
        }
    }
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: I know this is for a different object type than listed above, however the approach will still work with the properties adjusted.